# IE-7 Error with GWT Project

Tags: java, internet-explorer, gwt, internet-explorer-7

I recently took over a GWT project and began making necessary changes.  Everything was fine until one day someone viewed the project in IE-7.  There is an error msg that persists in two of the GWT panels or screens.  Also the final results after using the tool do now show properly, however they are emailed correctly.

Because I took over the project I am unsure as to what code is exactly causing this error.  I'm hoping someone else has some knowledge on what may be causing it or possible solutions so that I know where I should be looking.

From what I've read so far, the error can be caused by height or widths being defined with a negative amount of pixels, however I haven't seen this in the project.

Thanks for the help.  Error message below.

```
(Error): Invalid argument. number: -2147024809 description: Invalid argument.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you set the "user.agent" property in your *.gwt.xml file to include IE??